# Matrix norm inducted by infinite vector norm

Tags: normed-spaces

I'm dealing with a proof form a numerical analysis book whose name is given in the description, I think that I'm missing something very obvious.
The problem consists in the second part of the proof, exactly the highlighted part. Why do we have inequality sign instead of the equality sign?!

[image: Infinite norm proof taken form Numerical Analysis: Richard L. Burden, J. Douglas Faires - all copyrights reserved]

Infinite norm proof taken form Numerical Analysis: Richard L. Burden, J. Douglas Faires - all copyrights reserved

Comment: It's pretty hard to see, could you make the image bigger?

Comment: Is it ok now? @DH.

Comment: It simply says the moordinates is is greater than or equal to one particular coordinate…

Comment: moordinates?! That particular coordinate is equal to max sum(|aij|) and xj is all ones or -ones. Can you be more concrete? @Bernard

Comment: Moordinates are a special system of coordinates to find one's position in the moor, a rather peculiar kind of British differential manifold.

Comment: More seriously, set $y_i=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j$, the inequality says $\max\limits_{1\le i\le n}\lvert y_i\rvert\ge \lvert y_p\rvert$.

Comment: I know that by definition, but what is confusing me is how $y_p$ is defined. If $y_p$ is defined as the max of sum of |aij| why we don't have equality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $$S_i=\left|\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j\right|$$ for each $i=1,\ldots, n$. Then the inequality in question simply says that for $1\leq p\leq n$,
$$\max_{1\leq i\leq n} S_i\geq S_p.$$
Since we know that the maximum of a set must always be greater than or equal to any individual element of that set, the inequality holds. Equality is not achieved unless $S_p$ is itself the maximum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But take a look to the other part of the proof. If xj is all ones or -ones in dependency to a_pj and on the other hand we have the sum of |a_pj| defined as the maximum of the sum of |a_ij| then why we do not have equality there? @AMPerrine

Comment: @Christopher So is your question, "why can we not immediately say that the second expression in that line is equal to the last expression?"

Comment: If I say yes, you will say that $|a_1+a_2+...+a_n| \leq |a_1|+|a_2|+...+|a_n|$ and not the opposite. But I understand, just tell me why the way how sum of $a_{pi}$ is defined, does not imply equality there. Take a look into the whole proof.

Comment: @Christopher I have read the proof. If that is not your question, then you will need to be more clear about what you are asking.

Comment: Ok we see that: $S=\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{pj}x_{j}=\sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{pj}|=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{ij}| $
Now, $\max_{1\leq i\leq n} \left|\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j\right|$ does contain a sum which is S, if S is defined as it is defined(tha max of...) then why  $\max_{1\leq i\leq n} \left|\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j\right|=S$ does not follow instead of inequality?

Comment: So why not  $ \max_{1\leq i\leq n} \left|\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j\right|= \max \left \{\left|\sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j}x_j\right|, \left|\sum_{j=1}^n a_{2j}x_j\right|, ..., \left |\sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{pj}| \right|, ..., \left |\sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{nj}| \right|  \right \} =  \left |\sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{pj}| \right|$

Comment: @Christopher So you *are* asking the question that I thought you were. Yes, you could show that the second and last expressions were equal by using a different argument like $-|a_{ij}|\leq a_{ij}x_j \leq |a_{ij}|$, applying a summation, and then looking at the maximums of the absolute values. But none of that is necessary for what the authors are trying to show, and I don't see how it would improve the proof.

Comment: But by definition we have that 
$||A||_\infty=||A||_\infty \cdot ||x||_\infty \geq ||Ax||_\infty=\max_{1\leq i \leq n} \left| \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij} x_j \right |$
$=\left |\sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{pj}| \right|= \max_{1\leq i \leq n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}| $. 
So we showed the desired. So: $||A||_{\infty} \geq \max_{1\leq i \leq n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|$ @AMPerrine

Comment: With 'by definition' I referred to the use of inequality, which is true by definition, and not to the fact that: $\|A\|_\infty = \|A\|_\infty\cdot\|x\|_\infty$ which stands just in this case.
But I think that I understood the author in that step, he is just using a fact that is true in general to imply the $\geq$ sign. What I've said in the last comment is that It would be better if we imply the $\geq$ sign like I did, I think it's more accurate, isn't it?!